# multiple .pgpass files for different databases

Tags: postgresql

I use two PostgreSQL databases, one local and one remote.

Whenever I try to get access to these databases, I need different login credentials.

After entering these, I receive a request to save a pgpass file. When I answer yes, the current pgpass file gets overwritten. When I log in to the other database, I get the same request which results in a new pgpass file.

Can I use separate pgpass files, one for each?

Comment: "After entering these, I receive a request to save a pgpass file."  Who are you receiving this request from?  This seems to be a question about some unknown tool you are using. I'm not aware that PostgreSQL itself, or any tool which PostgreSQL ships with, which would issue such a request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a single `.pgpass` file with a line for each database, see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html). PostgreSQL wouldn't ask such a question — you must be dealing with some inferior client software. You can create an appropriate password file manually rather than letting the unknown program overwrite it.